# htaccess: Rewrite with several variables

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect a page like

`/topic/italian-page2.html` to `/index.php?s=italien$p=2`

or

`/topic/france-page4.html` to `/index.php?s=france$p=4`

but also (without page number)

`/topic/spain.html` to `/index.php?s=spain$p=1`

Right now I use

```
RewriteRule ^topic/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+).html$ /index.php?s=$1&p=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^topic/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?s=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

The first one (without page) works fine.
The second one doesn't.

It redirects to `/index.php?s=italian-page2&p=$2`

What did I do wrong? Where is my mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: I've just tried to escape the "page" using RewriteRule ^topic/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\-page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?s=$1&p=$2 [L].
Didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
RewriteRule ^topic/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)-page([0-9]*).html$  /?s=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^topic/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+).html$ /?s=$1&p=1 [L]
```

That works!